# SpriteKit camera is not centred with aspectFit

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, sprite-kit

My scene is set to be `.AspectFit`. I have camera node in scene center and it is connected. Everything works fine for iPad landscape, but when I rotate simulator or run in different device then iPad in landscape camera is not centred. Why?

This is for landscape with camera on center:
[image]

After rotation camera is not centred:
[image]

Similar issue is for e.g. for landscape iPhone5s:
[image]

Why is camera shifted with scene setting `.AspectFit` with other device then iPad in landscape?

You can try out or experiment with this [project on bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/sirljan/cameraoncenter) I made.

EDIT: When I don't use camera, everything is on its place.

Answer (score 1):

Set the scene anchor point to 0.5, 0.5 to center your camera onto the scene ,  there is an issue with the view to scene conversion, and will draw in the top left corner instead of the center.  (Also, you will notice your hello world is off, this is because it is not accounting for the anchor change)

Perhaps the lack of a camera will make the scene translate where it draws to inside of the black bars,  I have no idea.

Comment: Top left? Isn't this typo?

Comment: No, how is a typo?,  it is drawing to the top left corner of your view,  your view is the size of the entire screen,  then sprite kit puts the black bars in, which gets drawn over the scene, giving you the half chopped image

Comment: Few notes: When I change anchorPoint of scene to (0.5,0.5), camera is on center. When you add node to middle of the scene it is added to bottom left corner. Big drawback is I have to rewrite positioning of nodes from code on many places. And still. Main question was why camera is shifted while it is on right place. Your answer is helpful but it is actually only workaround. I would like to know why this is happening in the first place.

Comment: Already explained why,  there is nothing you can do about it except maybe report a bug to apple

Comment: also, middle of the scene is 0,0 when you change the anchor point

Comment: when you think about it, the bug does make sense,  It is drawing the camera contents at the center of the view,  then when it adds in the black bars it translates the entire scene to the right,  thus getting your problem.  Looks like apple needs to fix the order the translations occur, so that drawing happens to the center of the scene, not the view,  then translating won't effect it